# How to analyse data samples scattered in time?

Tags: statistics, signal-processing, time-series

I want to analyse data corresponding to events happening at **arbitrary moments in time**, and conveying quantitative information. My goal is to study the relationship between the sum of these quantities and the passage of time.

Some examples fitting this description would be: migration fluxes, network traffic, financial transactions. In an unit of time you can have two events with small quantities or one event with a bigger quantity, and they have a similar relevance because they are basically describing a flow. The problem is that there is not such a thing like an "unit of time". Time is continuous but my signal, in this case, is intrinsically discrete!

I do not even know whether is there a name for this kind of data, and i feel that before doing any kind of analysis, i need to convert it to time series. Is there a name for this conversion?

I find this important, because this conversion involves information loss, and it is not reversible. Since any time series has a sampling interval, multiple events falling within the same interval will need to be aggregated somehow, for example by calculating the sum of the value they convey. For example if i have a purchase for 100 at 18:30 on some day, and a purchase of 200 at 18:45 on the same day, i will need to aggregate this to a data point with a value of 300 for that day, or for the hour interval 18:00 - 19:00.

Now, this seems to me quite similar to resampling, and specifically downsampling, but i am not sure, because sampling is about a continuous signal recorded at a regular interval

Comment: You are constructing a database: a list of qualitative descriptions of selected events. For each event the precise time $t$ is known and stored. You now want to introduce a discrete time-scale $t'$. Obviously that is feasible. You say that the conversion leads to loss of information. But if you store both time-scales that can't happen. I am not sure what kind of (mathematical) problems you are corcerned about.

Comment: These are quantitative, not qualitative descriptions. Having a database or not, it does not matter. There are different mathematical or statistical problems related to my question:
1) is there a name for data with a similar structure?
2) is it necessary to convert to time series, for analysis?
3) can the transformation to a time series be tackled as a downsampling, using the theory of signal processing?

specifically i am interested in the third question. i thought that other members could point me to the correct name for this transformation, in order to browse existing literature on the topic

Comment: (1) Say the process is continuous (for example: the temperature in a room), but the measurements are performed at arbitrary moments. Then you can use interpolation to estimate the signal at other times. (2) Say the process occurs only at the recorded arbitrary times, and nothing happens in between (for example: radiation from a radioactive sample). Then it is useful to compute the cumulative value as a function of time. You may then smooth this function.

Comment: Data of the type you describe are called "unevenly spaced time series" or "irregularly spaced time series". Here is a link to the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unevenly_spaced_time_series Another useful keyword might be "stochastic" + "modelling" or "processes".

Comment: Very interesting! Your last comment seems to fully answer my question! The wikipedia page pinpoints the terminology, it calls the transformation to time series simply *interpolation*, and it lists some methods for analysing the data without transforming it to time series!